# Loop through table of datacontext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreach

What I would like to do is, loop through a datacontext and for each table found, select two different rows and compare the individual columns and see if the rows are equal.

So far I've made a method to compare the values of two rows and return true if all values of the rows are equal.

Now I would like to put this method into a `foreach` loop along the lines outline below:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(Utillities.dbconnection))
{
    foreach (Table t in db)
    {
        var row1 = from r1 in t where r1.id == constraint1 select;
        var row2 = from r2 in t where r2.id == constraint2 select;

        bool compResult = CompareRows(row1, row2);
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to construct the `foreach` loop, so I can make the above selections :(
I've tried `db.Mapping.GetTables()`, but I can't see how this gets me closer - I can only get the table-names in the datacontext, not the tables themselves. Are there a way to get a table entity from a string containing the tablename? Or am I missing something (likely something obvious)?

Any help or hints with the above `foreach` loop will be much appreciated.

Comment: Side note: you could use one query with `or` for both conditions and check if the distinct result contains 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work unless you implement CompareRows for every combination of te possible types available. You cannot pas an anonymous type.

You can use this approach to get all the tables/columns
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/07/30/linq-to-sql-trick-get-all-table-names.aspx

I would create dynamic sql statements and use DB.Executequery insted